Tkinter Button Not Behaving as Expected
So I have been working on a project mainly using the tkinter module, and when I started trying to use Buttons I have seen that I literally can not just click on them. I have to both click, hold, and drag the cursor a bit for the button to register a click. This phenomenon is true for event triggers as well, such as , , etc. This makes clicking not only extremely annoying but it is near impossible to double or triple click. At the very least, double clicking works as expected.
Here are a few variations I've tried and all failing to behave normally:
b = Button(self, text="test", command=lambda:print(1))

b1 = Button(self, text="test")
b1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: print(1))

b2 = Button(self, text="test")
b2.bind_all("<Button-1>", lambda e: print(1))

These all require clicking and dragging the cursor for the number 1 to be printed onto the terminal
What I was expecting was the button to trigger the bound command upon simply clicking and not having to click and drag for a command to register.
My python version is 3.9.12
My tkinter version is 8.6
got those from running
python --version
and in the python shell
import tkinter
tkinter.TkVersion
the above doesn't want to create new lines for some reason and I am new to stackoverflow so I dunno why.
I am now extremely confused because running "python -m tkinter" creates a basic gui with some buttons and those buttons behave perfectly fine. I have been trying to find the source code for creating that gui but I have been struggling to find it.

Can you please edit your question with information about your python version/OS? You can try to bind to "<ButtonPress-1>"

@TheLizzard thanks but I figured it out, it was really dumb

I figured it out. Initially I thought it might be the ttk module, but it was caused by making the root window fullscreen. For some reason, this breaks the behavior of the buttons.
